# Doesn't implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

this is my message class:

```
public class SMessage
{

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public string str{ get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int sendByAccountId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("sendByAccountId")]
    public virtual AccountModels account { get; set; }

}
```

this is my dto class:

```
public class MessageInformation
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }    
}
```

and  this is my method in repository:

```
public List<MessageInformation> GetAllMessagesForUser(int accountId)
{
    MessageInformation messages
    using (SishanContext Context = new SishanContext())
    {
         messages = (from m in Context.SMessages.ToList()
                    where m.AccountId == accountId
                    select new MessageInformation
                    {
                       m.Subject,
                       m.str
                    }).ToList();
    }
    return messages;
}
```

but, I have an  error:

> Cannot initialize type 'sishan.Models.MessageInformation' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Why are you calling .ToList twice? You might want to profile your query to see that the filter is being applied on the client rather than in the database (Where clause is not being passed to the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name the properties in the initializer, like this:

```
...
select new MessageInformation {
    Subject = m.Subject,
    str = m.str
}
```

Alternatively, you can provide a two-argument constructor, and call it:

```
public class MessageInformation {
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
    public MessageInformation(string subj, string str) {
        Subject = subj;
        this.str = str;
    }
}
...
select new MessageInformation(m.Subject, m.str)
```

Comment: Looks like he's also missing the parenthesis for the constructor; I don't think those can be omitted.

Comment: @Servy I'm pretty sure that you can omit them ([link](http://ideone.com/jO6LWe)). In fact, ReSharper routinely pesters me for including empty parentheses before curly brace initializers :)

Comment: Even though I'm not using ReSharper anymore, past usage has caused me to still obsessively remove those surplus empty parantheses...